# Can I run a dedicated power source through along with Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, poe

Instead of utilizing POE, what if I used a seperate power supply for power and Ethernet for data using 2-pair shielded Cat5. Has anybody ever tried this, or thought of it? Are there any theoretical problems?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. If you have unused wire pairs in your cable, you can use them for **clean** DC power, provided the current (and voltage) specs of your cable are not exceeded. 100baseT can run on 2 twisted pairs, leaving 2 pairs free in most cables. Higher (faster) than that will generally use 4 twisted pairs, generally leaving no pairs free. If your DC power is noisy, it could adversely affect data transmission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have to be done in a way it is safe. This means, if you connect your power-RJ45 connector/cable to an ordinary socket, then nothing should happen.

1. If you have a RJ45 cable, then you have to use one pair TX+ and TX- as GND. RX+ and RX- as +48V. (these wires are very long and have a high resistance, because of this the voltage should be relatively high)
   The reason for this is, each pair is connected in the receiver over a little coil and if the voltage on the two wires is the same, then there is no current flow and the coil will not be damaged.
2. If you connect the cable accidentally to an other network device with POE, then there should not be any current flow in the wrong direction. This means "POE 48V" and "POE GND" have to be on the same position as in the standard-cable.

Look at "10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX mit PoE Alternative B" in the table as an example:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RJ-Steckverbindung#Anwendungen

Comment: What do you mean by wrong direction? POE uses rectifiers to overcome the problem of direction, so it doesn't matter what the direction is on the device. You would need to use the same scheme on any PD in case a different cable is used.

Comment: @VoltageSpike - If you use GND-potential on pin 5 (PoE 48V) of the "power-network-cable" and you connect it with the switch, then all the other devices will not get power any more, because the line is getting hot or the power supply will be damaged because of this short circuit. Your devices will survive it, but not the power supply.

Comment: @MikroPower That's not true. A standard PoE source disconnects PoE power from port when it is not negotiated. And standard PoE supply is required to be floating, so you can short standard PoE positive or negative to ground and it must have no effect. And each port of PoE source can come from separate isolating modules. It would also have some protection for guaranteeing operation under faults. But you are correct, forcibly applying custom PoE to non-PoE device will damage either the custom PoE supply or non-PoE device.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this has been tried, and it is the reason why a need for a standard like PoE was apparent.

Theoretical problems include not being able to pass enough current at the voltage you need, or drop in voltage due to current you need. Or having some custom adapters at both ends.

The real danger is accidentally connecting your cable with custom power to a standard device which blows up because your supply provides power.

Answer (score 1):

While standardized Ethernet PoE can seem like a hassle sometimes, it has benefits. One of them is the safety aspects of the standard: a compliant PoE source and powered device are not likely to start fires or damage other equipment just due to the PoE aspect.

What you refer to is called *proprietary PoE*, and is a common cost-reduction strategy in CCTV and security applications.

If your application is low volume, then part cost isn't much of a matter vs. the development cost, so just go with standard PoE and use a PoE power extractor board at the powered end. It saves a lot of hassle, and PoE Ethernet switches can be sometimes bought even in grocery stores, or at least they are easy to get everywhere. Whereas a proprietary solution will take hardware from specialist CCTV/Security suppliers, so it will be harder to service if something breaks.